# Nutrient and Recommendation models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3, I have two models: `Nutrient` and `Recommendation`:

- `Nutrient` has_many `Recommendation`
- `Recommendation` belongs_to `Nutrient`

I am trying to implement the create method of the recommendation in the controller. Is this the proper way to do it?

```
def create
  nutrient_id = params[:recommendation][:nutrient_id]
  if nutrient_id.blank?
    #nutrient_id was blank in the submit, get other recommendation params and re-render 'new'
    params[:recommendation].delete(:nutrient_id)
    @recommendation=Recommendation.new(params[:recommendation])
    render 'new'
  else
    @nutrient = Nutrient.find(nutrient_id)
    if @nutrient
      #nutrient was found by id, create recommendation
      @recommendation = @nutrient.recommendations.build(params[:recommendation])
      if @recommendation.save
        redirect_to @recommendation
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      #nutrient was not found by id, get other recommendation params and re-render 'new'
      params[:recommendation].delete(:nutrient_id)
      @recommendation = Recommendation.new(params[:recommendation])
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fundamentally flawed, I'm afraid. You're not using Rails' abilities to your advantage at all.

For a simple create operation, your controller method rarely needs to be more than 10 lines or so. There's way too much going on in yours.

Start by nesting your routes:

```
 resources :nutrients do
   resources :recommendations
 end
```

Run `rake routes` to see how the routes now look. Basically, a recommendation will have a URL like `/nutrient/:nutrient_id/recommendation/:id`.

This means you'll have to make some changes to links in your views and your redirections. Where you could previously write `recommendations_path` and so on you'll now have to write `nutrient_recommendations_path(@nutrient)` and so on. Again, `rake routes` will show you what helpers you now have.

In your recommendation form, you'll have to do something like:

```
 <%= form_for [@nutrient, @recommendation] %>
```

so the form's action URL will be correct. An get rid of the hidden input that I assume you've added to the form as `recommendation[nutrient_id]`.

Inside the `RecommendationsController`, you can always get the "parent" nutrient by saying

```
 @nutrient = Nutrient.find(params[:nutrient_id])
```

as that param is given in the URL.

In the end, your `create` method will look like

```
def create
  @nutrient = Nutrient.find(params[:nutrient_id])
  @recommendation = @nutrient.recommendations.new(params[:recommendation])

  if @recommendation.save
    redirect_to @recommendation, :notice => "Recommendation created."
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

See something like [this post](http://ericlondon.com/posts/243-creating-nested-resources-in-ruby-on-rails-3-and-updating-scaffolding-links-and-redirection) for a more thorough `diff`-like walkthrough of the changes to make.

Note, that if Recommendation has further nested resources, you should use "shallow" routes, but that's left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you so much flambino, I knew I was on the wrong path I just didn't know how to ask the right question. Thanks for laying it all out, you've saved me a huge headache and probably a lot of future miss-steps.

Comment: @Mike No problem. When your code starts to smell (methods are too long, things are getting complicated, etc), just remember that in 99 out of 100 cases, you're trying to well-known problem. So always check if Rails can do it all already, or look for a gem that might do it. I highly recommend looking at [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/), [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/), and of course [Rails itself](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)